# Split data in columns and store it as two dimensional array

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

I have a data in this form:

```
49907 87063
42003 51519
21301 46100
97578 26010
52364 86618
25783 71775
1617 29096
2662 47428
74888 54550
17182 35976
86973 5323
```

......

I need to traverse it at the end like `for line in file`.

I want to split them like first column values store in array one and second column values store in array two, so whenever I call `Array_one[0], Array_two[0]` I will get the first row values like `49907 87063` and same for other values.

Comment: `left_col, right_col = np.loadtxt(<your_file>, unpack=True)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use space as a seperator.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="\s+", names = ["A", "B"])
print(df["A"][0])
print(df["B"][0])
```

**Output:**

```
49907
87063

for i in df.values:
    print(i)
```

**Output**:

```
[49907 87063]
[42003 51519]
[21301 46100]
[97578 26010]
[52364 86618]
[25783 71775]
[ 1617 29096]
[ 2662 47428]
[74888 54550]
[17182 35976]
[86973  5323]
```

Comment: i also dont get, its a mistake

Comment: @jezrael can I add a counter like A[counter]??

Comment: @MuhammadHassan - I think the best is create expected output in question... And I believe `Rakesh` give you nice answer for this :)

Comment: @jezrael i also said traverse till the end, because there are 4 thousand lines :(

Comment: @MuhammadHassan - I think the best is add expected output to question :)

Comment: So no reason for downvote ?, Sign...I can only help the point back a little bit.

Comment: @jezrael i need to traverse 4 thousand values with this kind of format, i will use loop but how to add counter??

Comment: @MuhammadHassan Are you looking for `df["A"].size` to get len on a column?

Comment: @MuhammadHassan just do value_counts

Comment: @Rakesh bro i need to print all the values in the array A and B,  with single loop, you did good job but what next, how i go further to print 1,2,3.... and so on values, your solution print only one row value

Comment: @Wen I need to print further values with loop, as this solution stops at (df["A"]['0]) (df["B"]['0])... how to print use one counter in single loop

Comment: @MuhammadHassan  `print(df.values)` should give you all values

Comment: @Rakesh i need values line by line with two different variables, so i can put the in a function as arguments like func(col1value , col2value)

Comment: @Rakesh with one single loop which traverse to the end

Comment: `for i in df.values:
    func(i[0], i[1])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) to extract directly into a `numpy` array:

```
A = np.genfromtxt(file, dtype=int)
```

Whitespace is the default delimiter.

You can then use standard `numpy` indexing / slicing:

- To extract the first row: `A[0]`; the second column: `A[:, 1]`.
- To extract the first element of the first row: `A[0, 0]`.
- To extract the first element of the second column: `A[0, 1]`

To iterate the entire array by row:

```
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    print(A[i])
```

Comment: can you add second column B, because i need put those values line by line in a function, as parameters, like function( column1 , column2)

Comment: i am still not clear, i want to put these two values separately as the arguments of a function like fun(column1 , column2) with a single loop which go till 4 thousand lines...

Comment: I suggest you read the `numpy` [indexing docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html). Unfortunately, there isn't a tutorial on SO.